# Loading Json to datatable

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, datatables

What am I doing wrong?
This is my code:

```
           $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "GetData.asmx/GetEventMembers",
            data: "{'ShulID': '" + ShulID
               + "','EventID': '" + EventID + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) 
                     {
                        $('#tblEventMembers').dataTable({                        
                            "aaData": eval(data.d)
                        });
                     },
            failure: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
```

This is my json:

```
{
  "aaData": [
{
  "MemberID": 22,
  "FName": "hfhfh",
  "LName": "fhfhfh",
  "InvitationDate": null,
  "Approved": false,
  "Invited": 0
},
{
  "MemberID": 42,
  "FName": "fkfk",
  "LName": "vm.,v",
  "InvitationDate": null,
  "Approved": false,
  "Invited": 0
}
  ]}
```

And I'm getting this error:

[image]

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: The JSON looks valid, the only thing I can spot is trying `data: {ShulID : ShulID, EventID : EventID},` as there is absolutely no need for a string there, and getting rid of the awful eval() call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it.
My problem was that i used the json response as is.
Now i added: `$.parseJSON()` and it's working well.
My code looks like this now:

```
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "GetData.asmx/GetEventMembers",
            //data: {ShulID: iShulID, EventID: iEventID},
            data: "{'ShulID': '" + iShulID
            + "','EventID': '" + iEventID + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            //sAjaxDataProp: "",
            success: function (jsonRes) 
            {

                var oTable = $('#tblEventMembers').dataTable({
                    "bDestroy": true,
                    "aaData": $.parseJSON(jsonRes.d).aaData,
                    "aoColumns": [
                                    { "mData": "MemberID" },
                                    { "mData": "FName" },
                                    { "mData": "LName" },
                                    { "mData": "InvitationDate" },
                                    { "mData": "Approved" },
                                    { "mData": "Invited" }
                                 ]
                });
            },
            failure: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

ajax `data` Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value

So try changing this :

```
 data: "{'ShulID': '" + ShulID
               + "','EventID': '" + EventID + "'}",
```

to this:

```
data : {
 shulID : ShulID,
 EventID : EventID
},
```